# How to make min heap in python to store edges and weight

Tags: python, priority-queue, min-heap

I have a list of edges `l=[(0,1),(0,2),(1,3)]` likewise, and I have list of weight of edges `l1=[0.23,0.45,0]`. Now I wanted to store edges in min heap manner, so that I can get access to minimum weighted edge.

Comment: Use [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)?

Comment: do you have a custom implementation of heap? post that so we can see where you're getting at, or otherwise use heapq module

Comment: No i don't have implementation of heap. I am not able find how can i use `heapq`.

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder now i got it using heapq.

Answer (score 0):

Now i got it, using `heapq` and do `heapify`.

First create list

```
l = [[0.23, (0, 1)], [0.45, (0, 2)], [0, (1, 3)]]
```

Then call

```
heapq.heapify(l)
```

Returning:

```
[[0, (1, 3)], [0.23, (0, 1)], [0.45, (0, 2)]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).